# In an C program I increase some integer elements in an array randomly. Values that were not incrased changed anyways. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have an integer array with 400 elements. I initialize every element with 0 (and even check if it is really 0 afterwards because I can't find the reason for this behaviour).

Then I choose 10000 random[1] indices and increase the array elements at these indices by one. None of the randomly chosen indices is bigger than 321 (which I do check for). However, after these 10000 random increases the array elements with index 399 or 398 are bigger than 0. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_INCREASES 10000
#define RESULTS_SIZE 400
#define ONES_IDX 2
#define TENS_IDX 1
#define HUNDREDS_IDX 0

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int decimalDigits[3];
    int results[RESULTS_SIZE] = {0};

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<RESULTS_SIZE; i++) {
        if (results[i]>0) {
            printf("%05d %05d \n", results[i], i);
        }
    }
    puts("---");

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_INCREASES; i++) {
        decimalDigits[0] = 0;
        decimalDigits[1] = 0;
        decimalDigits[2] = 0;
        for (int digitIncrease = 0; digitIncrease<3; digitIncrease++) {
            int digitIndex = rand()%(decimalDigits[ONES_IDX]>0 ? 2 : 3);
            if (digitIndex == TENS_IDX && decimalDigits[TENS_IDX] == 2) {
                digitIndex -= 1 + 2*(i%2);
            }

            decimalDigits[digitIndex]++;
        }
        if (decimalDigits[TENS_IDX] > 2 || decimalDigits[ONES_IDX] > 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error %d\n", __LINE__);
        }
        int toIncrease = decimalDigits[HUNDREDS_IDX] * 100 + decimalDigits[TENS_IDX] * 10 + decimalDigits[ONES_IDX];
        if (toIncrease < 0 || toIncrease > 321) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error %d\n", __LINE__);
        }
        results[toIncrease]++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<RESULTS_SIZE; i++) {
        if (results[i]>0) {
            printf("%05d %05d \n", results[i], i);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It happens with GCC and clang. I have seen it on 3 different machines. Neither valgrind nor gdb report any problems to me.

A sample output would be

```
---
00183 00020 
01763 00021 
03618 00111 
01263 00120 
01738 00201 
01068 00210 
00367 00300 
00183 00399
```

What is the error here? 399 shouldn't be in the second column of the output.

Footnotes:

[1] The random indices are generated by starting with the number 0. Then increasing one random decimal digit of that number 3 times. However, then "ones" digit is increased at most 1 time. The "tens" digit is increased at most 2 times.

Comment: I ran your code, compiled using clang on OS X, and what you describe did not happen. It also does not duplicate at http://ideone.com/0ngKK1. I think it's you.

Comment: Because you're probably generating indexes 398 and 399 with all that useless decimalDigits fiddling. If you want to randomly increase your numbers by 1, 10, or 100, then simply have `results[rand(400)] += 10*rand(0,2);`

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're using a negative index in `decimalDigits` and it is writing to the end of `results` (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line results in a negative array index when I run your code as is:

```
for (int digitIncrease = 0; digitIncrease<3; digitIncrease++) {
    int digitIndex = rand()%(decimalDigits[ONES_IDX]>0 ? 2 : 3);
    if (digitIndex == TENS_IDX && decimalDigits[TENS_IDX] == 2) {
        digitIndex -= 1 + 2*(i%2);
    }

    decimalDigits[digitIndex]++;  //Negative array index here
}
```

I would at least start looking in that block, i.e. it is not easy to follow, could be a mistake in your logic somwhere.

Comment: Ah. Yes it was supposed to be `digitIndex = digitIndex - 1 + 2*(i%2)`. Thanks.

Comment: @RotatingPieces That fixes the negative array index, but your logic still potentially allows for your ones place to be incremented more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing out-of-bounds elements of `decimalDigits`.

Try these 3 lines before the UB

```
        if (digitIndex < 0 || digitIndex >= 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error %d\n", __LINE__);
        }
        decimalDigits[digitIndex]++;
```